# perl6 signatures in POD

Tags: return, escaping, raku, quoting, code-documentation

since `-->` is the [preferred](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#index-entry---%3E-returns-Constraining_Return_Types) way to state the return type in a signature in perl6 I am wondering if or how it is possible to put the code of a function signature into `C<...>`.

e.g. `C<foo(Int $a --> Bool)>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `C<<foo(Int $a --> Bool)>>`.